# Can both "that"-s be dropped in "Here's the email that he sent that I mentioned"?

Tags: conjunctions, that, conjunction-reduction, which-that, correlative-conjunctions

Can both ***that***-s be dropped in "*Here's the email **that** he sent **that** I mentioned*"?  Is this grammatical: "*Here's the email he sent I mentioned*"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Great question!

Answer (score 1):

Both *that*s are functioning as relative pronouns which refer to the subject (the email). Individually, each clause would be fine without its *that*, but as a full *that*-less sentence it sounds odd, even if it happens to be grammatically "correct".

This sounds awkward:

> *"Here's the email he sent I mentioned."

This sounds quite natural:

> "Here's the email he sent that I mentioned."

I believe the reason for this is that without the second *that*, we expect the preceding verb to be one of feeling or reporting. For example, this sentence would work fine:

> "Here's the email (that) he **thought** (that) I mentioned."

In this case, both *that*s are optional. Also, notice that the second *that* in this example ends up functioning as a complementizer rather than a relative pronoun; it no longer refers back to the email, but rather connects with what "he said".

In short, the first *that* is optional, but the following clause(s), if they refer to the subject, should have *that* for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I voted to close the question as opinion-based. What sounds odd to someone does not necessarily hold true for many.

Comment: Can you  explain further on why the second *that* in your second example sentence, "Here's the email (that) he thought (that) I mentioned", is not a relative pronoun here but a complementizer? // Also, in the first example sentence, "Here's the email that he sent that I mentioned", is "the email" the antecedent for the relative pronouns of both the relative clauses, or only for the first one (with "the email that I sent" being the antecedent for the second relative clause)?